# Spring MVC Crud Application using AngularJs at front end

Tags: java, angularjs, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and AngularJs .
I was looking out for examples to integrate Spring MVC with AngularJs for creating a simple demo CRUD project , so that i can get my concepts cleared before starting to work on office projects .
Can anyone please provide me links which explains the working behind the scenes and not only static code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good example here right from the scratch.
https://dzone.com/articles/crud-using-spring-mvc-40

Comment: Thnk you ,but i need a little more explanation specially on jsp pages where angular is used and how controller and angular js are mapped